# Need to create agents on two Jenkins Controllers where it share same HOME space

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have two Jenkins controllers.
I am copying primary Jenkins `JENKINS_HOME` (`.jenkins/` directory) to secondary `JENKINS_HOME` to have same jobs, workspace and other user related information.

Now I need to create agents on both servers.
How can I do that ?

can someone share details on creating the agents on two jenkins controllers where it share same `JENKINS_HOME`

Comment: If you want to make one machine the master and the other the slave, you don't need to copy the jenkins home folder. What you're trying to do here is to make both machines Jenkins masters...